# Make category and Subcategory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form for Making Category and on the same page I am displaying the categories in form of tables. In front of each category there is a Add button to add subcategory. I want to display a modal which has a form for subcategory .

I am not able to add subcategory. When I click submit the submitted details are displayed in raw form and it is selecting only Id 1 everytime
[image]

**Controller**:

```
 public function subcat(Request $request, $id)
    {       

            $data = new SubCategories();
            $data->name = $request->input('name');
            $data->categories_id=$id;

            if($request->hasfile('image')){

                $file = $request->file('image');
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
                $file->move('uploads/subcategory/',$filename);
                $data->image = $filename;
            }else{
                return $request;
                $data->image = '';
            }
            
            $data->save();
            return redirect('/admin/addCategory')->with('Success', 'SubCategory Added');

    }
```

**Blade**

```
@extends('admin.master');

@section('content');
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
              <form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <label for="cat_name">Category Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="cat_name" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-dark">
              <tr>
                <thead>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>AddSubCategory</th>
                </thead>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($category as $col)
                <tr>
                 <td>{{$col->id}}</td>
                 <td>{{$col->cat_name}}</td>
                 <td><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="/admin/category/{{$col->id}}">Add</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
       

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add SubCategory</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{route('storeSub',[$category[0]->id])}}" method="POST">
                  {{csrf_field()}}
                  <label for="name">SubCategory</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                  <label for="image">Image</label>
                  <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->group(  function()  {
Route::get('/addCategory','\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index');
Route::post('/storecat','\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@categories')->name('store');
Route::get('/addCategory','\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@show');
Route::post('/category/{id}','\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@subcat')->name('storeSub');

});
```

Comment: You're missing javascript side. When you click add button, modal should open, then on that modal do what you want. I think you should first understand basic interactive form handling before laravel side :)

Answer (score 1):

Your probably not summiting a file, so the else statement is the path you are on. Because of this line

```php
else{ 
  return $request; // Remove This
  ...
```

Everything stops at that point and you are returning the raw form request data which Laravel is automatically turning into JSON. You'll need to remove that line in order for the rest of your method to continue processing.

Answer (score 1):

Because your modal is out of the `foreach`.

`action="{{route('storeSub',[$category[0]->id])}}"` on modal form can't handle above table's values.

Try to move modal area to foreach or, change modal's values with javascript dynamically.

The reason why everytime getting category id = 1 is, Because you're submitting on modal form action like

```
$category[0]->id
```

This means every time send category id = 1

So solutions is should be near to this in your blade file;

```
@extends('admin.master');

@section('content');
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
              <form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <label for="cat_name">Category Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="cat_name" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-dark">
              <tr>
                <thead>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>AddSubCategory</th>
                </thead>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($category as $col)
                <tr>
                 <td>{{$col->id}}</td>
                 <td>{{$col->cat_name}}</td>
                 <td><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="/admin/category/{{$col->id}}">Add</a></td>
                </tr>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add SubCategory</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{route('storeSub',[$col->id])}}" method="POST">
                  {{csrf_field()}}
                  <label for="name">SubCategory</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                  <label for="image">Image</label>
                  <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
       
        </div>
      </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Yea I did the same but still  taking category id = 1 only

Comment: @SSinha are you sure? did you changed  <form action="{{route('storeSub',[$col->id])}}" method="POST"> part?

Comment: Yes I did the same

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is in your javascript file that operate the modal class. Please provide more information on the related script.

Comment: I don't have any javascript script for this